# Checking if two inputs are integers and not already entered

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently writing a tictactoe program and I've ran into the problem of checking if two user `input`  both are integers and not previously entered.

```
def humanSelectABox(sign):
  parsed = False
  print("\n---Your turn ("+sign+")---")
  while not parsed:
    try:
      row = int(input("please choose row: "))
      col = int(input("please choose col: "))
      parsed = True
      if gamePlan[row][col] == EMPTY:
        return row,col
      else:
        parsed = False
    except AttributeError:
      print ("try again")
```

The string `if gamePlan[row][col] == EMPTY:` works by itself, and so does the `try: except:` as well. How do I check for both?

Comment: Well, I don't understand your question...what's wrong with your code? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `int` to convert string input from keyboard to number should handle checking whether the input is integer or not. If the input is not an integer, a `Value Error` is thrown. Catch that in `except` clause.

Regarding the input not being previously entered, you can collect all inputs into a list and then check if the current input is already in the list.

Comment: You're right for the most part, the problem doesn't lie in doing either of those, it lies in doing both. Right now I can edit the code only to use the `try: except:` which means that if I enter something that isn't an int. Or I use the `if gamePlan[row][col] == EMPTY:` which makes the program ask for another pair of inputs. 

I hope a screenshot of the program in action will help you understand what I meant by "not already entered" http://i.imgur.com/njEPYYH.png

Comment: Just kidding, I can't read, you were right about the ValueError.